# What is SNS App?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, internal-storage, system, social-networking-service

I'm using a Samsung Galaxy I551 with Android 2.2 FroYo.

Sorry for my ignorance, but I have not idea what is that app (which came installed and without rooting can't be removed). And it is using 15MB of my internal storage! I only have 160MB so that is a lot.

What is this app for? What will happen if I clear its data? Are those 15MB included in the storage DiskUsage categorize as "System Data"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Social Networking Service.  I believe it's used for social networking widgets.  Clearing the data will just clear the posts and account info in the widgets.  I'm not sure if the Facebook or other apps rely on it.

Comment: So, nothing bad should happen if I delete its data? It acts like a cache?

Comment: @Diego Yep it should be fine.

Comment: Nothing seem to went wrong.. Not even with Facebook widget! Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to force close the app from the Settings -> Application menu (but I had to do it 4+ times for it to stay gone, and I also tried a task killer on it before that but it came right back.)

Force close has kept it off for twenty minutes now! :) I hope it stays gone. I don't want to have to root yet.

Answer (score 1):

Just to enhance [Matthew's answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/12267/16575):

An "SNS" contact can also come from SKYPE if the app is installed.

I used to "Skype out" to my Dr. so skype knew his number. When I look up his name on my Samsung stratosphere phone, it is not found. However, I go elsewhere, get his number, and put it in, it pops up his name!  Frustrating!

Today I solved it: he can't be looked up as a "contact" but is in my *FAVORITES* (!! Favorites but not contacts ?? !!)  and when I "edit" (from putting his number and having the name come up) then it says "can't edit SNS data", which is how I got to *THIS* message thread. So yes, probably twitter, facebook, etc, but for sure "Skype" too!

Answer (score 1):

I think it is Simple Notification Service

Thus for platforms that use push notifications (Skype, Google+, Facebook, Twitter, etc) you will see this application updated from time to time.

Admittedly as a Network Security Professional, this made me pause when I saw it updated as my S4 is rooted, but turns out it is a normal item.

Answer (score 0):

Simple Network Service~
Wouldn't recommend uninstalling. Sometimes apps we think are garbage turn out have some dependencies from other apps. Boo boos involving deleting system apps can be hard to fix unless you make a backup in your custom recovery. BUT If you are curious or paranoid about what an unrecognized app says or does and to whom, behind your back... I recommend looking into an amazing app called Donkey Guard. Say for example FB wants to use your GPS to secretly locate you. Donkey Guard halts the app, Alerts you to what it wants to do. Then asks if you want to deny, allow function to app or submit your own fake info. Mine set up to give FB fake GPS coordinates that put me located at the Playboy Mansion. Or keep anything from being able to tell if your net is from data or wifi. It even stops apps from knowing anything about your data service including ISP provider and stop from using cell towers from location triangulation. Also works for location cheating/spoofing on games like Ingress or Pokemon, without having to hack and get banned.