# What does "SNS" mean on Android?

Tags: social-networking-service

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is SNS App?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/12265/what-is-sns-app)

Everything I try to do (Text, Video, Email, Call out, Apps, Games) I get an "SNS not working" message and have to force close.  I am having a lot of trouble with this phone.  Its a Cricket LG Droid.

Now a lot of my friends & family cannot receive my texts or calls.  It seems that all calls from my phone go directly to their voicemail without it even ringing.  No really, I stood right there with friends calling their phones and they never rang.  What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

SNS stands for social networking service.  I think your device is having problem in connecting to your sns accounts. To solve this problem, try this general solution- Delete all your SNS accounts and recreate them.